# Should a question be closed because it's apparently unanswerably obsolete?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

A user voted to close [openpyxl python3 -- formatting whole rows ellicits strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955243/openpyxl-python3-formatting-whole-rows-ellicits-strange-behavior) because:

> - It has no answers, accepted or otherwise;
> - The links to actual and desired output are dead;
> - The OP has not visited SO in nearly two years;
> - Any related openpyxl bug has probably been fixed by now;
> - It still shows up as an open question even though it's now effectively unanswerable.

Are those reasons sufficient enough for the question to be closed?

Comment: If `any related openpyxl bug has probably been fixed by now` can be proven then yeah

Comment: That's old stuff and unlikely being helpful in future research as it seems for me. Closing is OK IMHO.

Comment: We had that reason discussed in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27166829#27166829) room as well. I'll ask if someone wants to write an answer.

Comment: A user has now provided an answer to that question, disproving your 'not answerable' statement (if the answer is actually correct).

Comment: There is no evidence that proves that "it's now effectively unanswerable" so I don't see why it should be closed. If evidence is given then yes.

Comment: By the way, now it has [an answer with 4 upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33974541/5299236).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, it should not be closed for such reasons.

---

> - It has no answers, accepted or otherwise;

Since when is this a valid close reason? A very good, but hard, question can have no answer for a long time. It doesn't make it any worse. Perhaps the question hasn't received the attention it should have attracted and a bounty should have been placed.

> - The links to actual and desired output are dead;

That could be a valid close reason. It's a shame that the links are dead, such information should have been put in the question. However, even without that explicit information, the problem is still quite clear.

> - The OP has not visited SO in nearly two years;

Stack Overflow is a Q/A site where the goal is not just helping the OP but helping every individual that might have the same problem. I don't see any correlation between the fact that the OP hasn't visited the site for 2 years and the fact that an answer to the question could help a lot of different people.

> - Any related openpyxl bug has probably been fixed by now;

Such a claim must be backed by evidence. First, we would need to prove that the problem is in fact a bug of openpyxl, which wasn't done here.

> - It still shows up as an open question even though it's now effectively unanswerable.

Yes, it is an open question. Closing it because it "annoys" someone who is filtering by open questions isn't a valid reason. And again, nothing proves that the question is "now effectively unanswerable" (see the previous point).

Comment: Yes yes, well aware that SO answers are for everyone, not just the OP. My thought, rather, was that we won't be hearing any updates from the OP, nor can we ask for the lost output data again. Sorry, I should have made that clear. Your arguments and cybermonkey's comment have merit, and I've retracted my close vote. Thanks to everyone for their input.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

- The question *now* has an answer; even though at the time of commenting it didn't have an answer, that alone doesn't make a question unanswerable.
- It's a shame that the links are dead now, and there's really not much we can do about that.  But, do the images really need to be here for this question?  I can at least understand what's being asked of the OP without the images, so they're noise at best and the dead links should be edited out.
- The OP may not have visited in however many years, but the question is still getting views.  We're not going to get any clarifications from the OP, but this is one of those rare scenarios that we don't require any.
- Perhaps in newer versions of openpyxl,  this bug is fixed, but that doesn't mean that the question must be closed due to that.  If anything, a good answer would incorporate that knowledge into it, which is what seems to have happened.